# Firebase 3 - sends only a password reset link and no code

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase 3 no longer send a reset code with the sendPasswordResetEmail() method? I am only seeing a reset link in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has expressed interest in supporting sending code in addition to link for password reset. However there is no timeline when that will be ready.

One thing you can do is to create your own password reset landing page and parse the code from the url and display it to the user to copy into your app. I am guessing you are using a single page app and that is why you are interested in getting the code directly. Check the documentation for more on how to create your custom landing page.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler